# React Native - Refresh screen

Tags: react-native

I have the following app:

Main -> Login -> Favourites

On the main screen, you can click on a button called "Favourites" which:

1) If you are signed in, it will show your favourites

2) If you are not signed in, it will show the login screen

Let's say that someone is not logged in and they sign in to the application, this set's a key from an API and returns a alert saying "You are now signed in.."

Upon going back to the main screen after logging in, if they click on "Favourites" it will still show them the login screen. They have to close the app down and restart the app for the login to take effect.

What would be the most optimal way of making sure that they do not have to keep logging in?

Here is the main file:

```
  renderView() {


    if(this.state.token != null)
    {
        var data = this.getData();
    }else{
        console.log("token " + this.state.token);
        this.refs.nav.navigator.push({
          title: "Login",
          component: Login,
          rightButtonTitle: 'Cancel',
          passProps: {nav: navigator},
          onRightButtonPress: () => { this.refs.nav.navigator.pop(); }
        });
    }

  }


render() {
    return (

      <NavigatorIOS
          ref="nav"
          style={styles.container}
          initialRoute={{
              title: 'Home',
              component: Main,
              rightButtonTitle: this.renderIcon(),
              onRightButtonPress: () => {
                  this.renderView();
              }

          }} />

    );

  }

getData() {

  var query = urlForQueryAndPage('token', this.state.token, 1);

  fetch(query)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => this._handleResponse(json.response))
    .catch(error =>
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        message: 'Something bad happened ' + error
    }));
}
```

This is the main file and checks that if a token exists, it will navigate to the favourites or else it will navigate to login.

My Handle login inside Login.js:

```
    handleLogin(reply) {

      if(reply.body.response == 'true')
      {
          this.setServerKey(reply.body.key);
          AlertIOS.alert(
              "Login",
              "You are now signed in. Please go back to access your favourites!"
          );
      }else{

        AlertIOS.alert(
            "Login",
            "Wrong username/password. Please try again!"
        );

      }

  }
```

As you can see, the login will just do a pop up. But I need to refresh somehow the main screen in order to make sure that the favourites show up without the user having to re-login again.

Comment: In your `main.js` file, have you **fetched** the token and did `this.setState({token});` on `componentWillMount` cycle?

Comment: @tushar Khat - hi no I just did it in the controller

Comment: @TusharKhatiwada Hey did my reply get to you?

Answer (score 1):

### Avoid re-login after logged in

```
let token;

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.checkToken();
}

async checkToken() {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@MySuperStore:token');
    if (value !== null){
      token = value;
    } 
  } catch (error) {
    // Error getItem from AsyncStorage
  }
}

renderView() {
  if(token != null) {
    var data = this.getData();
  } else {
    //re-check because constructor only run once
    this.checkToken();
    if (token) {
      We have data!! therefore we getData() and redirect to favourites page
    } else {
      this.refs.nav.navigator.push({
        title: "Login",
        component: Login,
        rightButtonTitle: 'Cancel',
        passProps: {nav: navigator},
        onRightButtonPress: () => { this.refs.nav.navigator.pop(); }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

---

If you can save your token in persistent way instead of in volatile state then you can retrieve the value and check it after first time you obtain it.

In my mind, I have two ways can save the token in persistent way.

1. [AsyncStorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html)

> First, check if your token exists in AsyncStorage

```
try {
  const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@MySuperStore:token');
  if (value !== null){
    // We have data!! therefore we redirect to favourites page
  } else {
    // call getData() and handleLogin()
    // remember setItem token to AsyncStorage
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('@MySuperStore:key', token);
  }
} catch (error) {
  // Error retrieving data or setItem to AsyncStorage
}
```

2. [Redux](http://redux.js.org/) and [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist)

> you can retrieve token from the redux store that is persisted by redux-persist, but this might be time-consuming if you want to understand and implement the redux but it's worth it.

Comment: Thanks I use asyncstorage thanks not the problem. The issue is that I go from the home screen, set the token using storage then once going back to the main screen it still says I'm not logged in until I reset the app?

Comment: If you need to reset the app only get what you need, then it means, the way you trigger the function to set token state placed at wrong place, therefore it is only triggered when app restart. You need to find cycle function that will trigger even when you navigate from other page?

Comment: So your problem is after user logged it and you back to home, the token is not updated but need restart app to update it?

Comment: check my updated answer? does it solve your problem?